# Read data url in for each promise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise

I want to replace in my object a firebase child data image url by a database64 string. It work pretty well but i have issue with async ? how can i wait for all my value inside my foreach ?

```
 return FirebaseRef.child('rav').on('value', snapshot => {
    //   const userData = snapshot.val() || [];

    var obj = {

    }

    snapshot.forEach(child => {

      function toDataURL(url, callback) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload = function () {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onloadend = function () {
            callback(reader.result);
          }
          reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
        };
        xhr.open('GET', url);
        xhr.responseType = 'blob';
        xhr.send();
      }

      toDataURL(child.val().avatar, function (dataUrl) {
        // console.log('RESULT:', dataUrl)

        obj[child.key] = {

          ...child.val(),
          avatar: dataUrl
        }
        console.log('obj', obj)
      })



    });


    console.log('obj', obj)

    this.updateAvatar({ profile: obj }); // Send to reducer


  });
},
```

}),

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty array before the forEach, have the `callback()` function return a `Promise.resolve()`, push the return value (the promise) of `callback()` into your array, then (after the forEach) use `Promise.resolve()` with your array to trigger the action you want to call after all the FileReader() calls have completed.

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by stating that you shouldn't define a function inside a loop. It's redefining at every step of the loop. That's not your issue though. Lucky for you I wrote such a function earlier this year. This dataURL was found on wikipedia.

```js
function dataURLtoBlob(dataURL){
  var d;
  if(typeof dataURL !== 'string' || !((d = dataURL.split(';base64,')) && d.length > 1)){
    return false;
  }
  var s = atob(decodeURIComponent(d[1])), l = s.length, a = new Uint8Array(l);
  for(var i=0; i<l; i++){
    a[i] = s.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return new Blob([a], {type:'image/png'});
}
var url = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,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';
console.log(url);
dataURLtoBlob(url).text().then(function(str){
  console.log(str);
});
```

```html
<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,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'/>
```

Of course, you should ask yourself why you're doing this when you can [store an image in Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage).

PS

You should be able to send a Blob to your Server using [FormDataInstance.append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append).